Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group. Does there exist an exact sequence $0\to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\to G\to G\to 0?$
Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group.
My question is, does there exist an exact sequence $0\to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\to G\to G\to 0$ ?
If $G$ is finite group, from isomorphism theorem, there is not such a $G$.
But what about the case $G$ is an infinite group ?
Tensor the exact sequence $0\to \ker f\to G\xrightarrow{f} G\to 0$ with $\mathbb{Q}$. Then you get
$$
0\to\ker f\otimes\mathbb{Q}\to G\otimes\mathbb{Q}\xrightarrow{f\otimes\mathbb{Q}} G\otimes\mathbb{Q}\to 0
$$
Then $f\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is an isomorphism, because it is a surjective endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space. Therefore $\ker f\otimes\mathbb{Q}=0$, which means $\ker f$ is torsion, but $f$ need not to be injective.

For an (infinitely-generated) example you can consider a Prüfer group.

Not if $G$ is finitely generated.
If $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group, then $G$ can be written as $G\cong F\oplus T$, where $F$ is free abelian (of finite rank) and $T$ is finite.
The nontrivial element of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ will then map to an element of the form $(a,b)$ with $a\in F$ and $b\in T$. But since $F$ is torsionfree, $a=0$. Thus, the map must embed $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ into the torsion part.
Thus we are reduced to asking if you can find a finite abelian group $T$ that has a nontrivial subgroup $A$, a free abelian group $F$ of finite rank, and an isomorphism
$$F\oplus T \to F\oplus (T/A).$$
But two finitely generated abelian groups are isomorphic if and only if their free parts are of the same rank and their torsion parts are isomorphic. Thus, we would need $T\cong T/A$... and you've already noted that this cannot happen.

The question is equivalent to asking whether there is such a $G$ with $G\cong G/\Bbb Z_2$. The answer follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups.
